# Add button in admin columns

Tags: admin, columns

I would like to add a button next to the column name in e.g. edit.php admin screen. I have added a printsreen showing where I would like the button to go.. I have searched for available hooks but there appears to be none.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: @Harrrymandilas I have answered bellow and it should works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking code to add a column next to short link. It's pretty much simple. There are two things here. You can add it for specific post type or common to all the post types you have.

```
  // add a thumbnail column to the edit posts screen
  function kv_post_thumbnail_column($cols) {
       $cols['thumbnail'] = __('Thumbnail', '1stopwebsolution');
       return $cols;
   }
  add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'kv_post_thumbnail_column');


   // go get the attached images for   the logo and thumbnail columns
    function   kv_thumbnail_value($column_name, $post_id) {

        if (('thumbnail' == $column_name) || ('logo' == $column_name)) {

             if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 71, 61));

            }
     }
 add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'kv_thumbnail_value', 10, 2);
```

This will add a Thumbnail column next at last of all the post type's listing table.

You can create post type specific one with the following link.  Read more and get it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid this is not what I asked for. I am OK with adding custom columns. My question was how could I add a button (or any other html code) next to the name of a column. Something similar to `restrict_manage_posts`, but within the column header div..

Comment: You can add it like this. ` $cols['thumbnail'] = '<button name=" test button " ></button>;`.  But I am not sure whether this one works or not.

Comment: Yes this (your follow-up answer) was actually what I wanted to do.. Silly I did not think of it before asking. I thought i had at least tried that... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested add bellow code to your theme `functions.php`

```
  function firefog_post_edit_column($cols) {
       $cols['edit'] = __('Button', 'firefog');
       return $cols;
   }
  add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'firefog_post_edit_column');

    function   firefog_post_edit_value($column_name, $post_id) {
        if ('edit' == $column_name) {
             echo '<button class="button">Button</button>';
            }
     }
 add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'firefog_post_edit_value', 10, 2); 2);
```

Comment: This adds a button to all rows. What I wanted was to add a button just in the title of the column. The follow-up answer by [Akelya](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/81480/akelya) sorted it out.